# Using items from a list of base class to generic method

Tags: c#, generics

Hard to come up with a good title, but let's say I have this situation. I have a base class:

```
public abstract class FooBase
{

}
```

And I have a generic implementation:

```
public class MyFoo<T> : FooBase where T : Bar
{

}
```

So far so good. The abstract base is so I can create a heterogeneous collection of these generic items:

```
List<FooBase> list = new List<FooBase>()
{
    new MyFoo<Bar1>(),
    new MyFoo<Bar2>()
}
```

Now the problem comes here. I have a generic method:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(MyFoo<T> aFoo) where T : Bar
{

}
```

And this works when I call it with an instance of a *specific* `Foo`:

```
DoSomething(new MyFoo<Bar1>());
```

But I want a function that will take a list and call `DoSomething` on each item:

```
public void DoSomethingWithList(List<FooBase> list) 
{
    foreach (var item in list) 
    {
        DoSomething(item);     // doesn't work - type cannot be inferred here
    }
}
```

So is there a way, at *run-time* to get it to figure out the correct type and call the generic function? Or is there some other way out of this conundrum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dynamic typing - that will perform overload resolution at execution time with the *actual* type of the object that `item` refers to. You can simply change the iterator type to `dynamic` like this:

```
public void DoSomethingWithList(List<FooBase> list) 
{
    foreach (dynamic item in list) 
    {
        DoSomething(item);
    }
}
```

Note that if you end up with a `FooBase` in your list which *isn't* a `MyFoo<T>`, you'll get an execution time failure. You can avoid that (if you want) by providing another overload:

```
public void DoSomething(FooBase x)
{
    // This will be called for any items in the list that aren't
    // MyFoo<T>
}
```

Disadvantages of this approach:

- It has some performance impact; whether that's significant or not will depend on your app, but you should test it.
- You lose compile-time type safety.
- It doesn't work before C# 4, which is when `dynamic` was introduced.

If you *can* avoid getting into this situation by redesigning a bit, that's often a good idea... but sometimes you really do need something like this.

Comment: Lookout, as this is not type-safe

Comment: @Dzior: It's type-safe, just at execution time rather than compile-time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant strongly-typed :)

Comment: Looks promising. The signature for `DoSomething` was a typo on my part. It was meant to be `MyFoo<T>` rather than `T`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MattBurland: Okay - I'll edit my post to get rid of that part, and you fix the question :)

Comment: More or less it could be a possible place to generate some annoying bugs

Comment: @Dzior: So what's your practical alternative suggestion? Basically you *can't* fix this at compile-time. Now in some cases you can change the design, but sometimes this really is the cleanest approach. If the list is being constructed within the same class, the scope for problems is pretty small.

Comment: @Dzior [Strongly typed isn't really a meaningful term](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/10/15/is-c-a-strongly-typed-or-a-weakly-typed-language.aspx).  The term you're actually looking for is *statically* typed.  This solution is dynamically typed, not statically typed, because the type checks are deferred until runtime.

Comment: Yeah, I know we are losing some type-safety here but it feels like the problem really stems from not having a good way to define a list of generic types without creating a (potentially empty) non-generic base class. I know that the only implementations of the non-generic base class are generic, but there isn't a way to express that in the code. So there's always a danger that somebody else might try and derive from my base class.

Comment: Thanks Jon. It ran without throwing up any errors, so it seems like it's working and it looks like it called the generic method as expected. I'm making a note to revisit this at a later date to see if I can't rejig things to avoid this problem.

Comment: @AmitJoki Dzior is of course correct to be concerned about this solution.  It *is* a difficult position to be in and the solution has a number of pitfalls that programmers can easily fall into.  Of course, when in this particular position, there simply isn't any real way of avoiding that.  When the alternatives are not having it work at all, or a fragile undesirable solution that can actually work, it's not really much of a choice.  The main point is ensuring that you avoid this strategy when there is a statically typed alternative.

Comment: @AmitJoki Just because somebody wrote some books does not mean that you can't argue with this person. He's not a god.

Moreover discussion IMO is the best way to learn something

Comment: And now, citing Cartman, "Sc*** you guys, I'm going home", cheers

Comment: @Dzior: Your concerns are noted and appreciated (by me at least), but I do need a solution to this problem and this seems to work for the time being. I think everybody is aware that it's far from ideal and I will probably have to revisit this later and figure out how to rearrange this into something less fragile.

Comment: @Dzior, I'm sorry. But I left comments the way you did, but one of the guys told me to be kind. My comment wasn't disrepctive, but the guy said to use "Will not that be type unsafe?" instead of "Lookout its type unsafe"(*I used your comment as an example*). It was embarrassing for me, so thought I would make you not feel like that. Nothing wrong in arguing though ;)

Comment: We should stop, this is going way too off-topic 

Answer (score 0):

Nope, since generic types have to be known in compile time, and your example does not provide information to the compiler, what type should he use, you have to manually insert type in method call